# Javascript Clone Objects with Events

Tags: javascript, html, oop, dom

I am working in JavaScript, no libraries.

I just discovered cloning in JS and am trying to figure out how to clone an element but maintain the attached events.

From what I can tell this is not possible...

I tried to clone the element and then add the event and I tried adding the event first and then cloning, but the event is never copied over.

Here is my test code

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
    .testClass {
        background-color: red;
        color: black;
        outline-color: green;
        width: 100%;
    }

</style>

<script>

    function onLoad(){

        //create test div
        var x = document.createElement("div");
        x.id = "master";
        x.className = "testClass";
        x.innerHTML = "Text";
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        //clone the div
        var itm = document.getElementById("master");
        var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(cln);

        //apply event
        document.getElementById("master").onclick = doFunction;
    }

    function doFunction(){
        alert('working');
    }

</script>

</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">

</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect the code the cloned element does have the same ID, so why doesn't the event work when clicking the cloned element? It seems like because its a clone you can't attach an event to it.

Is this a limitation of cloned objects in JS?

Is it possible to add an event to a cloned object after it's created?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not that you cannot attach event handlers to it. But you cannot select it by its id when another element already has the same id. An id must be *unique*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few thoughts that I hope will help you:

First of all you're ending up with 2 elements with the same ID ("master"), only one of these will be selected by `getElementById`. Make sure you keep your IDs unique across the entire DOM! If you want the same identifier for multiple elements, use `class="master"` and `getElementsByClassName`.

If you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode, it states neither inline nor attached event listeners are copied, so you will have to re-assign them in code.

I suggest looking into `AddEventListener` and the likes, as that's what you will have to use after cloning to attach event listeners to your new DOM node.